# ASP.NET Core 1.0 ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(); function missing

Tags: asp.net-core

So I've finally got round to looking at Core and I've fallen at the first hurdle. I'm following the Pluralsight ASP.NET Core Fundamentals course and I'm not getting the `ConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFIle()` function. I have added the necessary namespace. But The function is not there.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: typo on AddJsonFIle i vs I in file?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. But got the solution. Need to add "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" in the project.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Will you need to install the nuget: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json